# Code for Checking and Changing Rows if needed

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This code should look at each row in the table and compare it's B and C values of the row to the row above it, for rows that meet the requirements it does nothing but each row that does not meet the requirements will be highlighted green if it does not meet the requirements.

The problem I'm having is getting the range or rows to work on line 3 and 4.

```
Sub IF_Loop()
Dim Row As Range
For Each Row In Range("A3:C155")
    If Row("B3").Value = "GR" And Row("B2").Value = 4 And Row("C3").Value = Row("C2").Value Then
        'Do nothing
    Else
        Row.Interior.Color = 9359529
    End If
Next Row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`For Each Row In Range("A3:C155")`

This isn't doing what you think it is. `Row` is just an iterable - naming it `Row` does not make it **represent a row**. `For Each Row In Range("A3:C155")` is iterating through every individual cell in `Range("A3:C155")`.

Additionally, your `If` will only ever test `B3`, `B2`, `C3` and `C2` - you need to have something variable in there to change with each iteration. Give this a shot instead:

```
Sub IF_Loop()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 3 To 155
        If Not (Range("B" & i).Value = "GR" And Range("B" & i - 1).Value = 4 And Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & i - 1).Value) Then
            Rows(i & ":" & i).Interior.Color = 9359529
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct to use a `For Each` loop was a good one. When working with objects a `For Each` loop can be [27x faster](https://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/) than the equivalent `For i = ...` loop.

The missing link for you was the `.Rows` property of a `Range` object. It allows you to loop through the rows of your range and you can access particular cells in that row using `.Cells`. For example, `Row.Cells(1,1)` is a reference to the first cell in the row.

So here's another way you could have achived the same thing:

```
Sub IF_Loop()
    Dim row As Range

    For Each row In Range("B3:C20").Rows
        With row.Cells(1, 1)
            If Not (.Value = "GR" And .Offset(-1, 0).Value = 4 And .Offset(0, 1).Value = .Offset(-1, 1).Value) Then
                row.Interior.Color = 9359529
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```